# Select and insert rows into multiple tables , sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert

How do I insert multiple rows into two different tables at the same time.

I have 3 tables

```
create table temp_source
(
  GroupID varchar(10) primary key,
  ExMsg varchar(20)
); 


create table temp_exceptions
(
  ExID int identity primary key,
  ExMsg varchar(20)
); 

create table temp_sjobs
(
  GroupID varchar(10) primary key,  
  ExID int 
);
```

`temp_sjobs.ExID` has a foreign key relationship to `temp_exceptions.ExID`

Now I want to insert all the rows from `temp_source` table into `temp_sjobs` and `temp_exceptions` table at the same time.

The only way I could do it is to loop through each row in `temp_source` table, insert the row into `temp_exceptions` table, get the `@ExID = scope_identity()` and insert that row into the
`temp_sjobs` table.

This seems very slow and query takes lot of time because of looping.

Is there a better way to do the insert into multiple tables at the same time.

Comment: Why dont you first insert into exception table and then soure table ?

Comment: Thats what I am doing, but then I have to loop through each row.

Comment: Isn't this a one off job? You will have to remove the foreign key for a bulk insert and add again, if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Using the OUTPUT Clause could help your case, Please find below the sample query

```
DECLARE @temp_source table
(
 GroupID varchar(10) primary key,
 ExMsg varchar(20)
); 

DECLARE @temp_exceptions table
(
 ExID int identity primary key,
 ExMsg varchar(20)
); 


INSERT INTO @temp_source Select 1,'message1'
INSERT INTO @temp_source Select 2,'message2'
INSERT INTO @temp_source Select 3,'message3'
INSERT INTO @temp_source Select 4,'message4'


DECLARE @temp_sjobs table
(
 GroupID varchar(10) primary key,  
 ExID int 
); 


DECLARE @temp_InsertedExceptionOutput table
(
    ExID Int,
   ExMsg varchar(20)
)

INSERT INTO @temp_exceptions (ExMsg)
OUTPUT inserted.ExID, inserted.ExMsg into @temp_InsertedExceptionOutput
Select ExMsg from @temp_source

INSERT INTO @temp_sjobs(GroupID,ExID)
SELECT ts.GroupID, eo.ExID
FROM @temp_InsertedExceptionOutput eo
JOIN @temp_source ts on ts.ExMsg = eo.ExMsg


Select * from @temp_source
Select * from @temp_exceptions
Select * from @temp_sjobs
```

With the table design you have i assume the ExMsg are unique else you may find integrity issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can do the following - probably the easiest way:

```
SELECT INTO temp_sjobs FROM temp_source
SELECT INTO temp_exceptions FROM temp_source
```

If you wanted to do it all at the same time, you could this as a **CTE** or **CURSOR**.  Other than that, you would have to do it as a **TRIGGER** - basically, if there was a new entry in **temp_source**, it would **INSERT** a new record into **temp_sjobs** and **temp_exceptions**.

Comment: This won't work because it doesn't create the foreign key relationship between temp_sjobs and temp_exceptions. It also doesn't take the column data types into account.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet would be to use two insert statements

```
INSERT INTO temp_exception (ExMsg)
SELECT DISTINCT ExMsg
  FROM temp_source

INSERT INTO temp_sjobs (GroupID, ExID)
SELECT ts.GroupID, te.ExID
  FROM temp_exceptions te
  JOIN temp_source ts
    ON ts.ExMsg = te.ExMsg
```

First build the temp_exception table and then create the temp_sjobs table and link the two together.

Comment: @SoumyaK I just made small edit (`SELECT DISTINCT`). Will it work if we make sure `ExMsg` is unique within the `temp_exception` table?

Comment: No, I just want to add the corresponding identity of the inserted exception(temp_exceptions) into the 2nd table(temp_sjobs)

Answer (score 0):

As what I understand, you want to split up your table temp_source into temp_exceptions and temp_sjobs with a foreign key relationship between them. I also faced same situation some times back and I had opted a solution like below for better performance:

```
declare @Exid int
select @Exid = max(ExID) from temp_exceptions 

if @Exid is null
set @Exid = 0

set Identity_insert temp_exceptions ON

insert into temp_exceptions (ExID, ExMsg)
select @Exid + row_number() over(order by (select NULL)), ExMsg from temp_source

insert into temp_sjobs (ExID, GroupID)
select @Exid + row_number() over(order by (select NULL)), GroupID from temp_source

set Identity_insert temp_exceptions OFF

select * from temp_exceptions;
select * from temp_sjobs;
```